# Функция, возвращающая текстовый бэкап БД MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, резервное-копирование, mysql

Сабж, существует ли такая?

Answer (score 1):

Всеведущий Google с ходу предлагает массу вариантов :) Основных подходов два (программных):

1. Резервировать каждую таблицу отдельно, выполняя запрос `SELECT * ...` и сохраняя результат в файл, для восстановления использовать `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`
2. Вызвать `mysqldump` через `system()` или `shell_exec()`

Оба варианта с примерами кода рассмотрены в [этой статье](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Такой функции не существует, используй различные утилиты, например: mysqldump, phpmyadmin или любую другую утилиту.